# RESTAssured/Serenity jBehave ExamplesTable throwing "Not a Map or List type" exception

Tags: bdd, rest-assured, jbehave, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I have the following `Given` statement:

**ServiceSatus.feature:**

```
Given I run a request for service status with the following options
|field1  |field2     |field3  |
|all     |1517029200 |5234817 |
```

**StepDefinition.java:**

```java
private HashMap<String,String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();

@Given("I run a request for service status with the following options")
public void i_run_a_request_for_service_status(ExamplesTable featureOptions) {
    options.put("field1",featureOptions.getRows().get(0).get("field1"));
    options.put("field2",featureOptions.getRows().get(0).get("field2"));
    options.put("field3",featureOptions.getRows().get(0).get("field3"));    
}
```

Cucumber is identifying this as a valid `Examples Table`, however I am getting an error saying it's not a Map or List type.

> Cucumber exception: Not a Map or List type: class org.jbehave.core.model.ExamplesTable

Do I have some type of syntax error in my feature file?

**EDIT:**
I'm using jBehave ExampleTables on top of rest-assured, bdd-serenity, and cucumber for jUnit.

**pom.xml:**

*Dependencies:*

```xml
<properties>
    <serenity.version>1.9.1</serenity.version>
    <serenity.maven.version>1.5.8</serenity.maven.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
    <maven.failsafe.plugin.version>2.18</maven.failsafe.plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.2</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
    <serenity.cucumber.version>1.9.1</serenity.cucumber.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.7</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-cucumber</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbehave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160810</version>
</dependency>
```

*Plugins:*

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${serenity.maven.version}</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>serenity-reports</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>aggregate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Could you please provide full code snippet (including imports) and used dependencies (part of pom.xml or build.gradle)?

Comment: Have you tried renaming ServiceSatus.feature -> ServiceSatus.story ?

Comment: @VaL added dependency info

Comment: @VaL it's pulling in and reading from the feature file just fine. it's even parsing the file. The problem is that I can't use `getRows()` on it

Comment: Replace `org.jbehave.core.model.ExamplesTable`with `cucumber.api.DataTable`

Comment: @VaL I ended up doing that but I wanted to get it to work with ExampleTable

Comment: You are mixing up JBehave and Cucumber models. It's better to choose one BDD framework and follow its model.  If you still want to use `org.jbehave.core.model.ExamplesTable` as step input parameter in Cucumber context, you should implement a custom transformer.

Comment: @VaL oh ok that's fair. If for all intents and purposes cucumber's DataTable works (and it does) I'm fine with staying with that. If you want to post that last comment as an answer (with your explanation) it might be helpful for future readers to find that solution as this framework doesn't have many resources online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBehave and Cucumber models are mixed:

- JBehave: `org.jbehave.core.model.ExamplesTable`
- Cucumber: `cucumber.api.DataTable`

These classes are analogues, they represent the same class of objects (BDD tables), but belong to different libraries.

It's better to choose one BDD framework and follow its model. But if it's still required to use `org.jbehave.core.model.ExamplesTable` as step input parameter in `Cucumber` context, a custom transformer should be implemented: https://static.javadoc.io/info.cukes/cucumber-core/1.2.5/cucumber/api/Transformer.html